# bootstrap carousel - 2 carousel in the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I decided 2 use bootstrap carousel to show some pictures of some projects, but sadly I have some problems with this. 
I want 2 carousels on the same row, but this seems like an impossible mission. 
I have tried to use css where I give the outter div a width on 100% and then created to "inner divs" with a width on 40 % each. 
Sadly this doesn't solve the problem.

```
<div class="outterBound row">
                    <div class="insideSize">
                        <!-- This is the slideshow, all the css works and the pictures wont be too wide -->
                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
                            <!-- Indicators -->
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                                <!-- remember to add the number of pictures here, else the idicator wont work! --> 
                            </ol>

                            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img  src="/img/sogo/Photo 26-05-16 15.52.38.png" alt="login">
                                </div>

                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="/img/sogo/Photo 26-05-16 15.52.41.png" alt="frontPage">
                                </div>

                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="/img/sogo/Photo 26-05-16 15.52.50.png" alt="updateProfile">
                                </div>

                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="/img/sogo/Photo 26-05-16 15.53.10.png" alt="createAccount">
                                </div>

                                <!-- just add another "item" here if you want more pictures  -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- Left and right controls -->
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- slideshow ends here, you can add/remove pictures as you want to. -->


                    <div class="insideSize">
                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
                            <!-- Indicators -->
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <!--<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li> -->
                            <!-- remember to add the number of pictures here, else the idicator wont work! -->
                        </ol>

                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img  src="/img/sogo/diverse/Billede1_1.jpg" alt="login">
                            </div>



                            <!-- just add another "item" here if you want more pictures  -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- slideshow ends here, you can add/remove pictures as you want to. -->
                </div>
            </div>
```

and here is the css file:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

p{
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 14px;
}


.font{
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.padding{
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.jumbotron p{
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 16px;
} 
h4{
    align-items: left;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img{margin:0; max-height: 70%;}

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 40%
    margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1023px){
    div.outterBound{
        width: 100%;

    }
} 

@media screen and (min-width: 1023px){
div.insideSize{
    width: auto;
}
}
```

Any ideas? 
Here's a link for the [website](http://lassejohansen.dk/portfolio) so you can see it with the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bootstrap column.

```
<div class="outterBound row">
    <div class="insideSize col-sm-6">
        First Carousel
    </div>
    <div class="insideSize col-sm-6">
        Second Carousel
    </div>
</div>
```

Be carful with the use of ID, an ID is unique, you can't have two id="myCarousel". Change the id for each carousel or use class.